# How to find out Packet Loss in a Broadcasting environment

Tags: wireless, communication, wifi

Indeed packet loss is an important metric to use when comparing different communication protocols.

To me it is understandable how one would computer Packet Loss in a unicast transmission. Simply the ratio between the number of sent packets to the destination node vs. the number of received packets by that destination node.

But, how would one compute Packet Loss in a Broadcasting scenario? There is no specific destination. The packet is received by everyone. How to handle such a case?

Comment: You have to evaluate the packet loss separately for each receiver. There's no meaningful way to combine the measurements into a single number. However, you could potentially create a coverage map that's based on some sort of "standard" receiver+antenna configuration.

Comment: does it make sense if I look at the average packet loss rate for all the nodes in the network?

Comment: You could, but how would that number be useful to you?

Comment: for example looking at the overall packet loss (for all nodes) as the number of nodes in the network increases? does this make sense?

Comment: Why would it increase at all? As an extreme example, look at GPS: There are roughly 26 transmitters, but literally billions of receivers, and yet the "packet loss" for any given receiver depends only on that receiver's particular situation.

Comment: because in my scenario a single broadcast from "master" node "fires-up" 1 broadcasts from each node. Which means, if "master" node broadcasts at time 0, at time 1 each node (that "heard" master's broadcast) will broadcast itself. As such the network gets loaded and I expect that much packets are lost. However I can not find a way of measuring packet loss so far :(

Comment: Why didn't you say that to begin with? Everything you said up to this point implied that it was a one-way transmission. For what you're (now) talking about, you need a collision avoidance or collision recovery protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Send sequence numbers and look for gaps.

In each packet sent, include a counter value that gets incremented with each packet sent. On the receive side, monitor these numbers. If a packet does not get received, then there will be a gap in the sequence.